# JavaFX Simple Calculator - Calculate Button Action

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a Simple JavaFX Calculator for school, I am stuck on putting together an Action Event that take the input from both text fields, the radio button that is selected, and the perform that event when the calculate button is pressed.

```
        btnCalc.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
}
public void calculation(ActionEvent e) {
    int num1, num2, answer;

    num1 = Integer.parseInt(tfNum1.getText());
    num2 = Integer.parseInt((tfNum2.getText()));

    if (rbAdd.isSelected()) {
        answer = num1 + num2;
    } else if (rbSubtract.isSelected()) {
        answer = num1 - num2;
    } else if (rbMultiply.isSelected()) {
        answer = num1 * num2;
    } else {
        answer = num1 / num2;
    }

    tfAns.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
```

[Program Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l940.png)

Comment: Try getting rid of `ActionEvent e` in `public void calculation(ActionEvent e)`. Then try `btnCalc.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            calculation();
        }
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function btnCalc.setOnAction() asks for an EventHandler as parameter. What this will do is every time you press the button, it will execute the handle() method of that EventHandler (which is empty in your case). You can solve that in 3 different ways:

- You call your calculation(ActionEvent e) function in the handle(ActionEvent e) function of the EventHandler (if you do this, you can delete the ActionEvent parameter from calculation().
- You copy your code from calculation(ActionEvent e) into handle(ActionEvent e)
- The best option here probably is to use a lambda. When an interface has just 1 function, you don't have to "make" an object of the interface but you can just give the function in the following way:

```java
btnCalc.setOnAction(e -> calculation());
```

In this case you can also remove the ActionEvent e from the parameters of calculation().

So the total code would look like this:

```java
        btnCalc.setOnAction(e -> calculation());

public void calculation() {
    int num1, num2, answer;

    num1 = Integer.parseInt(tfNum1.getText());
    num2 = Integer.parseInt((tfNum2.getText()));

    if (rbAdd.isSelected()) {
        answer = num1 + num2;
    } else if (rbSubtract.isSelected()) {
        answer = num1 - num2;
    } else if (rbMultiply.isSelected()) {
        answer = num1 * num2;
    } else {
        answer = num1 / num2;
    }

    tfAns.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
```

Comment: Every interface with 1 method can be replaced by a lambda and in they even say explicitely [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html) that it's a "functional interface". (You probably didn't really learn that in school, but it's always a good idea to read documentation). For more info on what lambda's are, you can check out [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp).